# Using Ajax To generate A Select Box

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My AJAX works fine but when I want to populate Select box, I get nothing displayed:

My HTML:

```
<div id="sim-div"></div>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).on('change', '#hotspotList', function(){
    var selectedHotspots = $('#hotspotList').val();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "simList.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
        data: selectedHotspots
    }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success
        $("#sim-div").html(data.items);
    })
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My PHP:

```
$test = '
<select  id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker"   data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple>
<option>test</option>
</select>
';
echo json_encode(array('items'=>$test));
```

When I change `$test= 'something';` it works and I get the word 'something' displayed.

When I log , `console.log(data.items);` and I get :

```
<select id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple> <option>test</option> 
</select>
```

But when I delete the options of select (id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" ), it works, seems like the problem in the cotes, but I need them

Comment: what about `.html(data["items"])` ? or json_decode(data) ?

Comment: try to log the content of "data" when you receive it. Then it will be easy to find how to use it...

Comment: @Random, I console.log(data.items); and I get : <select  id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker"   data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple>
                                                   <option>test</option>
                                        </select>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', '#hotspotList', function(){
    var selectedHotspots = $('#hotspotList').val();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "simList.php",
        type: "POST",           
        data: selectedHotspots,
        success:function(data){
              $("#sim-div").html($.parseHTML(data));
        }
    });
});
```

My php :

```
echo $test = '<select  id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker"   data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple>
<option>test</option>
</select>
';
```

hope it will help..

Comment: $("#sim-div").html($.parseHTML(data)); you are getting as a string, now you need to convert to html element

Comment: then use $("#sim-div").html($.parseHTML(data.items)); with  dataType:"json",

Comment: <select  id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker"   data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple>
<option>test</option>
</select> keep it in double quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="sim-div">
<select id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple> <option>test</option> <option>test4</option> 
</select>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).on('change', '#hotspotList', function(){
    var selectedHotspots = $('#hotspotList').val();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "simList.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
        data: selectedHotspots
    }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success
        $("#sim-div").html(data.items);
    })
});


</script>
```

In simList.php

```
$test = '
<select  id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker"   data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple>
<option>test</option>
<option>teste</option>
</select>
';
echo json_encode(array('items'=>$test));
?>
```

now i tested and working fine also

Comment: here removed   e.preventDefault(), $.parseHTML

Comment: doesn't work, when I remove ( id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker"   data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true") it works

Comment: Could we move the <select  id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker"   data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple>
to the html file ?

Comment: can you please paste as it is and run, 100% it will work

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="hotspotList" name="hotspotList" class="selectpicker" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" multiple>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option> 
</select>
<div id="sim-div">        
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('change', '#hotspotList', function(){

    if( $('#hotspotList :selected').length > 0){
        //build an array of selected values
        var hotspotList = [];
        $('#hotspotList :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
            hotspotList[i] = $(selected).val();
        });

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "simList.php",
            type: "POST",           
            data: {'hotspotList':hotspotList},
            success:function(data){
                  $("#sim-div").html(data);
            }
        });        
    }   

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> simList.php

```
<?php
$output = "Selected values are ".implode(',',$_POST['hotspotList']);
echo $output;
?>
```